# What is a good way to implement a data report grid on my MVC3 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Before I start work I would like to get some ideas. What I have is an MVC3 page that I currently use to display rows of data. There are many rows so I would like to filter them. Ideally at the top of my page I would like to have a select drop down box and a refresh button with rows of data appearing below when the refresh button is clicked.

I can imagine doing this with Ajax and then having the data from my controller populate new HTML text between a DIV.

Does this sound like the best approach? I am not looking for a person to write code for me. Just want to be sure my solution sounds like a good way to go.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

i recommend this approach:
http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can 'enchance' it with AJAX of course, but do not forget about users with disabled javascript. Make it work without client scripting, then enchance it, when its working.

I also think that you can simply create controller action, that is accepting parameters like pageNumber and amountOfItems. Then in your controls at page, you can just change values (number of page etc..) and use them in call for your controller action at form submit.